Volume under a normal distribution in cartesian and polar not integrating to 1
This is my first calculus problem in several years as a professional. I'm checking to see that my integral of a normal distribution works, so that I can use it as a weighting function for approximating particle beam heating.
I'm using MathCAD, which does all the difficult u-subs (or equivalent) under the hood. I have confirmed that it gives the right answer for the integral of the gaussian (in polar) e^-r^2 as pi
integral of gaussian in polar
My particular normal curve is in the form often given which uses a standard deviation sigma and an expectation value mu. The problem I'm having is that while this function integrates to unity in one dimension as expected, in 2D it integrates to some odd value of 2.507 and I don't know why this should be the case.
integral with sigma = 1 and mu = 0
I can't find any reference to this value of 2.507, and would have thought the normal curve would integrate to pi, since it integrates to 1 in 1D like it should. The factor of 1/sigma*sqrt(2 pi) is what seems to cause it. Where am I going wrong in my thinking?
And here's my whole page that captures everything all at once:
Whole page with graphs in 1D and 2D cartesian and integrals in 1D, cartesian, and polar

$\sqrt{2\pi}=2.50662827...\approx 2.507$

The volume under any distribution function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$ or $100$%.

@Semiclassical That's so strange! I didn't notice. Did you have any guesses as to why it came out that way?

@m-stgt ok, so why does mine not (until I normalize it)? Is there something wrong with the way I have it written in 2 dimensions?

@DavidKonyndyk -- Have a look here, the text is in German, but not so the formulas. Guess you'll see the difference.

The $\sqrt{2\pi}$ you end up with is due to a missing factor in the denominator of the 2D density function. You should have integrated
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac1{\color{red}{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2+(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then their joint density is the product of their individual densities.

Oh now I feel silly. I guess I'm a bit rusty! That's really awesome that you could help me out. I showed my young son my work and explained to him how I needed help with my math, so it was a teaching moment for him as well. Thanks!
